# WildFly 8/JBoss: General way to debug Java EE classloader linkage errors

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8, linkageerror

what is the right way to debug those issues?

In my case I have massive troubles with a LinkageError within my Java EE web project:

**Problem**

I included JSF API (jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar) into my wildfly modules directory, i.e. it will be loaded by Wildfly classloader.
I have external libraries which also depend on that JSF implementation (e.g. Primefaces and OmniFaces).
Additionally, to let the build process run without errors I have to add the library as an separate EAR library.

The strange manner is when adding a bean that implements function with faces event paramaters, e.g.

```
public void myValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
 // do sth. 
}
```

implementing those functions results in ...

```
10:22:18,571 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent in Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @468a169f (finder: local module finder @13d344e7 (roots: /home/user/app-server/wildfly8/modules,/home/user/app-server/wildfly8/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent"
```

... starting point for my SEVERE

```
10:22:18,578 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/faces/event/ValueChangeEvent"
```

(removing the parameter allows to build the project without errors)

**Question**

How to cope with such problems? I would need an overview about the order the classes are loaded. Probably there is a way to show an entire classloader tree or any profiling tool which will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable debug or trace logging on JBoss Modules, but that's bound to be too much information.

In your case, why do you add a module (i.e. jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.5.jar) which is contained in WildFly anyway (exactly the same version in 8.0.0.Final)? That's why the module loader is complaining about duplicate classes.

There is a list of implicit module dependencies for WildFly deployments (which includes jsf-api for JSF deployments). If you need additional dependencies from the WildFly distribution, you should simply declare that dependency instead of duplicating the module.

See [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) for more details.

Comment: Well, you are right not to add the library manually into the project. Another issue was a missing separation between business logic and web tier. Now I removed the particular jsf implementation but when I try to catch my event within my action listener implementation, my bean is not instantiated during deployment because of a class loading error: Type javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent from [Module "deployment.myApp.ear.appCore.jar:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.